# Is there any way in python to auto-correct spelling mistake in multiple rows of an excel files of a single column?

Tags: python, nlp, spell-checking

I am working on the Sentiment Analysis for a college project. I have an excel file with a "column" named "comments" and it has "1000 rows". The sentences in these rows have spelling mistakes and for the analysis, I need to have them corrected. I don't know how to process this so that I get and column with correct sentences using python code.

All the methods I found were correcting spelling mistakes of a word not sentence and not on the column level with 100s of rows.

Comment: What do you mean by **column level**??

Comment: I mean to say if I have an excel or CSV file with multiple columns and one column only contains text. For that column is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Spellchecker  for doing your stuff

```
import pandas as pd
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell  = SpellChecker()

df = pd.DataFrame(['hooww good mrning playing fotball studyiing hard'], columns = ['text'])

def spell_check(x):
    correct_word = []
    mispelled_word = x.split()
    for word in mispelled_word:
        correct_word.append(spell.correction(word))
    return ' '.join(correct_word)


df['spell_corrected_sentence'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: spell_check(x))
```

[image]